# qsub jobs with low priority?

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub, torque

I want to submit a couple of jobs to a cluster, but I want them to execute only if there are no other jobs on queue. How can I do this?

The cluster uses TORQUE+MAUI management system.

Answer (score 1):

Maui may not be able to do this. I have looked over the documentation for Maui for a negative or positive affinity and hpenable but I did not see any references to it. I did see references in the main product Moab which is based off Maui. These may not be in Maui but I though I would mention them in case it works for you.

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/8-1-0/enterprise/help.htm#topics/moabWorkloadManager/topics/resourceAccess/managingreservations.html#affinity

So in the mainstream product you would do something like:

```
SRCFG[res1] CLASSLIST=prio+,~lowprio-
```

This tells the software to positively draw in prio class jobs. The ~ for lowpro tells the software to ignore this credential until all of the prio jobs are evaluated/started/ran. The "-" says to not run in this reservation unless no other resources are available. You then just add a task count to consume the entire cluster.

The other option is to submit all of those jobs with a hold and have a cron job do a qstat and check for other jbos before releasing the jobs with a releasehold .